# .Net Core 3.1 Azure Web App - Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, adal

I have an Azure Web App that authenticates a user which then navigates to a page where some Sharepoint documents are retrieved and displayed in the app.

Most of the time the application works fine, but ocassionally App Insights will highlight that `Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken`. Some users report issues from time to time on this page (it's inconsistent so it might happen a few times a day with a somewhat large user base). The problem is that currently the error isn't handled and I'm trying to figure out how to make the call to `AcquireTokenAsync`.

The following is the method that returns the token (or doesnt):

```cs
private async Task<string> GetUserAccessToken()
{
    try
    {
        // Credentials for app
        // _clientId and _clientSecret represent the app info - not shown here in code
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(_clientId, _clientSecret);
        
        //Construct token cache
        ITokenCacheFactory cacheFactory = Request.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenCacheFactory>();
        TokenCache cache = cacheFactory.CreateForUser(Request.HttpContext.User);
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(_authority, cache);
        
        // guid of the user currently logged into the app
        string objectID = _userObjectId;
        UserIdentifier userIdentifier = new UserIdentifier(objectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);

        string resource = "https://test.sharepoint.com";
        
        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, credential, userIdentifier);
                
        return result.AccessToken;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

If I understand the flow correctly, the web app here will request a token using it's own credentials on behalf of the user currently logged in. (Am I right in understanding this based on the method signature which states - `Identifier of the user token is requested for. This parameter can be Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifier.Any.`)

Now when this fails, I would need to make a call to `AcquireTokenAsync`. There are a number of these methods available and I can't seem to find the one that will fulfill this requirement.

Before the suggestion comes, I can't use `AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, redirectUri,new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));` because the constructor on `PlatformParameters` has changed and requires an implementation of a `ICustomWebUi` and this flow isn't supported on .Net Core 3.1 as far as I'm aware which makes this unusable.

`AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credentials)` works and returns a token, however, when using that token I get a 401 Unauthorized when accessing the Sharepoint resources, most likely because the token is different and it is now requested on behalf of the application and not the user logged into the application (if I'm following this train of thought correctly...).

My question is - which method do I call? Is there something I would need to add before making the call to `AcquireTokenAsync` and if so, which of the 10 or so overloads should I use? I tried using `AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credenetial, userAssertion)` and passed in the AccessToken that I retrieved on the `User` logged in, but then I got `Assertion failed signature validation` or variations on that. If I understood correctly, the `UserAssertion` can be initialized with 1,2 or 3 parameters and I tried providing the AccessToken currently on the user that is logged in the app, but with no success.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I've been looking at this for two days now.

Comment: Seems you want to use OBO flow : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow  to get an access token to call Sharepoint  API?

Comment: Not so much that I want to use it, but it seems that this is what was used. Now based on the diagram on the Microsoft page, this flow would be one app short as it's a web app calling sharepoint and the obo flow has webapp -> api 1 -> api 1 calls api 2. But yes, I guess this is the closest to it I guess. I'd be happy to prompt the user in the case of a failure but not sure I can seeing as the app is .net core based on what the documentation says for .net core prompt support ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent more time investigating this, but none of the methods available would have worked in my case. The auth flow wasn't an on-behalf-of flow, but an [auth-code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow). The link is to the newer MSAL library, but the concept is there. The application, a .net core web app, directs the user to sign in. When they sign in, an auth-code is passed into the response once they successfully authenticate.

The auth-code is then used to call `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(AuthCode, Uri, ClientCredential, UserIdentifier)`. This returns the valid access token that can be stored in the distributed token cache and then used to authenticate in order to access a given resource.

My biggest issue was that the error says you need to use AcquireTokenAsync to retrieve a new token. This is correct to a certain point, because in order to make any calls to any of the 14 or so methods you will need different bits of information, which will be dependent on the way you have setup your authentication flow in your application.

Because the application I worked on used auth code flow, I would need to get a new auth code. This would mean redirecting the user to login, capture the auth code in the response if the login was successful and then call the appropriate AcquireTokenAsync method that takes in an auth code as parameter along with app info, uri and so on.

To solve this, I used the information provided by the Microsoft Github page on [Acquiring tokens with auth codes in web apps](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-with-authorization-codes-on-web-apps). Here I found samples on how auth flow is setup, but most importantly, how to trigger a new authentication flow if the user needs to be re-authenticated.

I wrapped the code that would throw the `AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException`, catch the error and return a [`RedirectToAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

```cs
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "Controller", new RouteValues);
```

The above redirects the user to a given action, in a particular controller and passes through an object that can hold additional parameters. In my case it's a `new { redirectUri = redirectUriString}`, which is a string object that holds the URL the user would try to navigate this. I constructed this with a little method that uses the current HttpRequest to find the url the user was trying to get to.

Next, the controller that I had setup which responds to that redirect:

```cs
[HttpGet("/SignIn")]
public IActionResult SignIn([FromQuery(Name ="redirectUri")]string redirectUri)
{
    return Challenge
        (
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = WebUtility.UrlDecode(redirectUri) },
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        );
}
```

Here, a [`Challenge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.challenge?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is returned. The challenge triggers a call to the authentication flow that was setup in the `Startup` class. I think the entire flow here is that the method will send people to go through whatever is in that startup, which, in the case of the application I worked on, it prompts the user to sign in, captures the auth code, requests a new access token and once this is received and saved in the distributed token cache, the user is redirected to the `redirectUri` that I passed through.

I hope this helps or at least gives a starting point to anyone who might encounter a similar issue.